# How can I perform disk clean up on set of hosts

Tags: bash

I need to find out hosts in a cluster that have disk space > =85% .. I’m able to get this far

```
host df -h  / | awk ‘{print $1,$5 }’

# Output


<host1>

Filesystem Use%
/dev/mapper/vg-root 88%


<host2>

Filesystem Use%
/dev/mapper/vg-root 68%


<host3>

Filesystem Use%
/dev/mapper/vg-root 95%
```

When I do

```
df -h  / | awk ‘{print $1,$5 }’ | awk ‘$2 >=85 {print}’
```

then it omits hostname from the output.

I want to see hosts that have disk utilization >=85%. Like this

```
host1
85%

host3
95%
```

and in a next output, I would like to see hostnames only

```
host1
host3
```

then I would like to run our custom playbook to clean the disk space on those host

e.g.

```
diskclean.yaml host1
diskclean.yaml host3
```

Thank you

**The output of host df -h /**

```
host1 :

Filesystem                  Size   Used  Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg-root         20G    18G   2G    90%   /

host2 :

Filesystem                  Size   Used  Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg-root         14G    11G   3.4G  77%   /


host3 :

Filesystem                  Size   Used  Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg-root         12G    11G    1G   91.6%   /

host4 :

Filesystem                  Size   Used  Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg-root         15G    15G    0    100%   /

host5 :

Host didn’t respond. [No response]
```

**host5 output is a noise.**

Comment: once you start an awk process, see if you can't implement all of your logic in that once process. Maybe `awk '$2>85 {print $1,$5}'` might be enough. Good luck.

Comment: Can you please share the output of `host df -h  / `

Comment: I posted the output above .. for some reason, unable to format it properly here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
host df -h  / | awk ‘{print $1,$5 }’ | grep -oE '<(.*)>|[0-9]+%'| sed 'N;s/\n/ /;s#[<>%]##g'| awk ' {if($2>=85) print $1"\n"$2"%\n"}'
```

Demo:

```
$cat file.txt 

<host1>

Filesystem Use%
/dev/mapper/vg-root 88%


<host2>

Filesystem Use%
/dev/mapper/vg-root 68%


<host3>

Filesystem Use%
/dev/mapper/vg-root 95%
$grep -oE '<(.*)>|[0-9]+%' file.txt | sed 'N;s/\n/ /;s#[<>%]##g'| awk ' {if($2>=85) print $1"\n"$2"%\n"}' 
host1
88%

host3
95%

$
```

For only print hostname

```
host df -h  / | awk ‘{print $1,$5 }’ | grep -oE '<(.*)>|[0-9]+%'| sed 'N;s/\n/ /;s#[<>%]##g'| awk ' {if($2>=85) print $1}'
```

Demo:

```
$grep -oE '<(.*)>|[0-9]+%' file.txt | sed 'N;s/\n/ /;s#[<>%]##g'| awk ' {if($2>=85) print $1}' 
host1
host3
$
```

Comment: Didn't return a desired output

`grep -oE '<(.*)>|[0-9]+%' file.txt | sed 'N;s/\n/ /;s#[<>%]##g'| awk ' {if($2>=85) print $1"\n"$2"%\n"}'`
6
100%

Comment: How many rows you have in file with > 80. Also why not directly run `host df -h  / | awk ‘{print $1,$5 }’ | grep -oE '<(.*)>|[0-9]+%'| sed 'N;s/\n/ /;s#[<>%]##g'| awk ' {if($2>=85) print $1"\n"$2"%\n"}'`

Comment: I did try what you suggested, but it threw wrong output.  The output is 
67
88%
# of rows > 80 can't be static  rather these are based on disk utility of hosts on a cluster in any given day.
Thanks